# Can I create a custom java.* package?

Tags: java, package

Can I create a package of my own that has the same name as a predefined package
in Java, such as `java.lang`?

If so, what would the results be? Wouldn't that enable me to access that package's **protected** members?

If not, what prevents me from doing so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No - `java.lang` is prohibited. The security manager doesn't allow "custom" classes in the `java.lang` package and there is no way telling him to accept them.

You're right - own classes declared in the `java.lang` namespace would allow you to use `protected` methods and members of classes in that package, and this is definitly not wanted.

---

This compiles fine - but - try to execute it ;)

```
package java.lang;

public class EvilAsEvilCanBe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hehe");
    }

}
```

Comment: i just gave java.lang as an example package ? and you said that the security manager would prevent it. but does this mean that i can do  that for example with a third party package not having a security manager or some kind of licensing ?

Comment: @AB Najjar - sure - you can declare *your* classes in the same namespace (=package) as other tools. And then you can use *their* package private classes, methods and fields. And *they* can use yours. **But**: consider this as technically possible and usually bad practise. Use the other libs in a cooperative way, usually people know *why* they declare stuff package private.

Comment: and that would grant me access to that package protected members ?!  isn't that awkward or even wrong ?

Comment: Not always. Just think about a library and its unit tests. The tests are kept in a separate jar and the test classes are declared in the same packages. This allows testing package private functions. Very useful.

Answer (score 3):

Any package name matching "java.*" is prohibited and a security exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things preventing you.

1) The license agreement. "Note: Applications that use this option for the purpose of overriding a class in rt.jar should not be deployed as doing so would contravene the Java 2 Runtime Environment binary code license." http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

2) You have to use the `-Xbootclasspath:bootclasspath` or add a lib/endorsed directory.

Some classes are not easily modified due to internal optimisations in the JVM e.g. you cannot add more than one method to Object to Sun/Oracle's JVM ;)