# How to get character array which is inside StringBuilder to avoid array copy

Tags: java, string

Is there any way by which I can get character array stored inside StringBuilder to avoid creating copy of it when I do toString(). Since, it is a primitive array so it is like deep copy and I would like to avoid generating this garbage.

Comment: "Since, it is a primitive array so it is like deep copy" - what do you mean by that?

Comment: You call the toString() method on the StringBuilder?

Comment: This seems like too much of optimization.

Comment: You want a `StringBuilder` that writes to a preallocated buffer? Or you want a `StringBuilder` that moves its buffer to the `String` when `toString` is called? Neither is possible with the `StringBuilder` class. You could implement the former yourself, but the latter is impossible.

Comment: @Jon It means when you do System.arrayCopy which toString() uses internally, a new array containing the shallow copy of the contents of the original array. But, in case of primitives shallow and deep copy are same.

Comment: System.arrayCopy is a highly efficient native routine. Unless you've profiled your application and identified this as the source of bad perfomrnace, I'd say you're optimizing prematurely

Comment: I'd say that "deep copy" is a meaningless concept when it comes to primitives. I don't believe you can get at the underlying buffer for StringBuilder, without nasty reflection.

Comment: @Sean...I understand the native call is blazingly fast. But, the garbage generation is my concern. Nature of my application is such that the business makes it to generate a lot of strings. Using toString() on StringBuilder is just doubling my total garbage.

Comment: I don't think that there is a way to get the complete Array, but StringBuilder offers some methods to acces the single characters in the Buffer (charAt(), length(), delete(), insert(),...) So you should be able to use the StringBuffer for everything that you could do with an array. I.e. With charAt() and length() you could iterate over the String as you would do that with an array.

Answer (score 9):

Avoid doing `stringbuilder.toString().toCharArray()` as it will allocate the memory twice.

Use something like :

```
char[] charArray = new char[stringbuilder.length()];
stringbuilder.getChars(0, stringbuilder.length(), charArray, 0);
```

Using reflection is also a bad idea as it may not be compatible with future java version and you'll have to resize the array as its size is probably bigger than the `StringBuilder` length see `StringBuilder#capacity()`

Answer (score 6):

You can treat the `StringBuilder` as a `char[]`, the bridge is supported by the interface [`CharSequnce`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html)

Calling the method `charAt(int index)` is "equal to" `array[index]`

The array is a private field that is not exposed to the public customer, due to encapsulation.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't.

Check the source of [StringBuilder](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#AbstractStringBuilder).

`char value[]` is the character array stored inside StringBuilder, and it's reference can be accessed only through [getValue](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#AbstractStringBuilder.getValue%28%29) method, which is NOT public.

Therefore, either use [toString](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#AbstractStringBuilder.toString%28%29) or [getChars](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#AbstractStringBuilder.getChars%28int,int,char%5B%5D,int%29)

Comment: You can make a proxy class in `java.lang` though and access it from there.

Comment: i already know this...the intention of the question is to get the optinal implementations available if any. I can implement it on my own, but am checking if same concerning to any other programmer on the web.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut, You can not make a proxy class in any package that start from `java` due to its restriction build in default class loader. You will get a securiry exception

Comment: yes, [creating custom classes in java.* is prohibited.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678194/can-i-create-a-custom-java-package)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using reflection:

```
Field stringbuilderCharField = StringBuilder.class.getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("value"); 
stringbuilderCharField.setAccessible(true);
char[] charArray = (char[]) stringbuilderCharField.get(pString);
```

And as StringBuilder is mutable, this is actually a nice way to use it.
You can do the same for String, but not advisable, as String is immutable.

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose 'str' is an instance of StringBuilder class that holds some string.
The simplest way to convert str to char array is as follows:

'*str.toString().toCharArray();* '